# Getting End Point in ArcSegment with Start X/Y and Start+Sweep Angles

Tags: .net, wpf, geometry, drawing, geometric-arc

Does anyone have a good algorithm for calculating the end point of `ArcSegment`? This is not a circular arc - it's an elliptical one.

For example, I have these initial values:

- Start Point X = 0.251
- Start Point Y = 0.928
- Width Radius = 0.436
- Height Radius = 0.593
- Start Angle = 169.51
- Sweep Angle = 123.78

I know the location that my arc should end up at is right around X=0.92 and Y=0.33 (through another program), but I need to do this in an `ArcSegment` with specifying the end point. I just need to know how to calculate the end point so it would look like this:

```
<ArcSegment Size="0.436,0.593" Point="0.92,0.33" IsLargeArc="False" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
```

Does anyone know of a good way to calculate this? (I don't suppose it matters that this is WPF or any other language as the math should be the same).

Here is an image. All values are known in it, except for end point (the orange point).
[image: image depicting arc]

---

**EDIT:**
I've found that there is a routine called [`DrawArc` with an overload in .NET GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxw9hsz1.aspx) that pretty much does what I need (more on the "pretty much" in a sec).

To simplify viewing it, take the following as an example:

```
Public Sub MyDrawArc(e As PaintEventArgs)

    Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
    Dim x As Single = 0.0F
    Dim y As Single = 0.0F
    Dim width As Single = 100.0F
    Dim height As Single = 200.0F

    Dim startAngle As Single = 180.0F
    Dim sweepAngle As Single = 135.0F

    e.Graphics.DrawArc(blackPen, x, y, width, height, startAngle, sweepAngle)

    Dim redPen As New Pen(Color.Red, 2)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(redPen, New Point(0, 55), New Point(95, 55))
End Sub

Private Sub ImageBox_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles ImageBox.Paint
    MyDrawArc(e)
End Sub
```

This routine squarely puts the end point at `X=95, Y=55`. Other routines mentioned for circular ellipses would result in `X=85, Y=29`. If there was a way to **1)** Not have to draw anything and **2)** have `e.Graphics.DrawArc` return the end-point coordinates, this is what I would need.

So now the question gains some clarity - does anyone know how `e.Graphics.DrawArc` is implemented?

Comment: are you referring to [StreamGeometryContext.ArcTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometrycontext.arcto.aspx)? as I cant really find a Sweep Angle there...

Comment: @Markus Hütter: Sorry, I had been told that the initial values were an `ArcTo`, but upon looking up that and `ArcAngle` in the GDI+ documentation, it doesn't look like that is exactly what it is. I've significantly modified the question to reflect the real ask.

Comment: @Stan would you be so kind to tell us what exactly the start and sweep angle depict?

Comment: @Markus Hütter: I've updated with an image - hopefully that will help in the visualization of what I'm trying to do given the current values I have.

Comment: @Stan: What is this "other program" that is calculating the end-point?

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: All Office programs, and now .NET GDI+ as above.

Comment: You might want to check out this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758377/given-bounding-rectangle-starting-angle-and-sweep-angle-how-to-determine-poin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does anyone know how e.Graphics.DrawArc is implemented?

`Graphics.DrawArc` calls the native function `GdipDrawArcI` in gdiplus.dll.  This function calls the `arc2polybezier` function in the same dll.  It appears to use a bezier curve to approximate an elliptical arc.  In order to get the *exact* same end-point you're looking for, we'd have to reverse-engineer that function and figure out exactly how it works.

Fortunately, the good people at [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) have [already done that for us](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/gdiplus/gdiplus.c#L217).

Here is the arc2polybezier method, roughly translated from C to C# *(note that because this was translated from Wine, this code is licensed under [LGPL](http://www.winehq.org/license))*:

```
internal class GdiPlus
{
    public const int MAX_ARC_PTS = 13;

    public static int arc2polybezier(Point[] points, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2,
                              double startAngle, double sweepAngle)
    {
        int i;
        double end_angle, start_angle, endAngle;

        endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle;
        unstretch_angle(ref startAngle, x2/2.0, y2/2.0);
        unstretch_angle(ref endAngle, x2/2.0, y2/2.0);

        /* start_angle and end_angle are the iterative variables */
        start_angle = startAngle;

        for(i = 0; i < MAX_ARC_PTS - 1; i += 3)
        {
            /* check if we've overshot the end angle */
            if(sweepAngle > 0.0)
            {
                if(start_angle >= endAngle) break;
                end_angle = Math.Min(start_angle + Math.PI/2, endAngle);
            }
            else
            {
                if(start_angle <= endAngle) break;
                end_angle = Math.Max(start_angle - Math.PI/2, endAngle);
            }

            if(points != null)
            {
                Point[] returnedPoints = add_arc_part(x1, y1, x2, y2, start_angle, end_angle, i == 0);
                //add_arc_part returns a Point[] of size 4
                for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    points[i + j] = returnedPoints[j];
            }
            start_angle += Math.PI/2*(sweepAngle < 0.0 ? -1.0 : 1.0);
        }

        if(i == 0)
            return 0;
        return i + 1;
    }

    public static void unstretch_angle(ref double angle, double rad_x, double rad_y)
    {
        angle = deg2rad(angle);

        if(Math.Abs(Math.Cos(angle)) < 0.00001 || Math.Abs(Math.Sin(angle)) < 0.00001)
            return;

        double stretched = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(angle)/Math.Abs(rad_y), Math.Cos(angle)/Math.Abs(rad_x));
        int revs_off = (int)Math.Round(angle/(2.0*Math.PI), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) -
                       (int)Math.Round(stretched/(2.0*Math.PI), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        stretched += revs_off*Math.PI*2.0;
        angle = stretched;
    }

    public static double deg2rad(double degrees)
    {
        return Math.PI*degrees/180.0;
    }

    private static Point[] add_arc_part(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2,
                                     double start, double end, bool write_first)
    {
        double center_x,
               center_y,
               rad_x,
               rad_y,
               cos_start,
               cos_end,
               sin_start,
               sin_end,
               a,
               half;
        int i;

        rad_x = x2/2.0;
        rad_y = y2/2.0;
        center_x = x1 + rad_x;
        center_y = y1 + rad_y;

        cos_start = Math.Cos(start);
        cos_end = Math.Cos(end);
        sin_start = Math.Sin(start);
        sin_end = Math.Sin(end);

        half = (end - start)/2.0;
        a = 4.0/3.0*(1 - Math.Cos(half))/Math.Sin(half);

        Point[] pt = new Point[4];
        if(write_first)
        {
            pt[0].X = cos_start;
            pt[0].Y = sin_start;
        }
        pt[1].X = cos_start - a*sin_start;
        pt[1].Y = sin_start + a*cos_start;

        pt[3].X = cos_end;
        pt[3].Y = sin_end;
        pt[2].X = cos_end + a*sin_end;
        pt[2].Y = sin_end - a*cos_end;

        /* expand the points back from the unit circle to the ellipse */
        for(i = (write_first ? 0 : 1); i < 4; i ++)
        {
            pt[i].X = pt[i].X*rad_x + center_x;
            pt[i].Y = pt[i].Y*rad_y + center_y;
        }
        return pt;
    }
}
```

Using this code as a guide, along with a bit of math, I wrote this endpoint calculator class *(not LGPL)*:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

internal class DrawArcEndPointCalculator
{
    public Point GetFinalPoint(Point startPoint, double width, double height, 
                               double startAngle, double sweepAngle)
    {
        Point radius = new Point(width / 2.0, height / 2.0);
        double endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle;
        int sweepDirection = (sweepAngle < 0 ? -1 : 1);

        //Adjust the angles for the radius width/height
        startAngle = UnstretchAngle(startAngle, radius);
        endAngle = UnstretchAngle(endAngle, radius);

        //Determine how many times to add the sweep-angle to the start-angle
        int angleMultiplier = (int)Math.Floor(2*sweepDirection*(endAngle - startAngle)/Math.PI) + 1;
        angleMultiplier = Math.Min(angleMultiplier, 4);

        //Calculate the final resulting angle after sweeping
        double calculatedEndAngle = startAngle + angleMultiplier*Math.PI/2*sweepDirection;
        calculatedEndAngle = sweepDirection*Math.Min(sweepDirection * calculatedEndAngle, sweepDirection * endAngle);

        //Calculate the final point
        return new Point
        {
            X = (Math.Cos(calculatedEndAngle) + 1)*radius.X + startPoint.X,
            Y = (Math.Sin(calculatedEndAngle) + 1)*radius.Y + startPoint.Y,
        };
    }

    private double UnstretchAngle(double angle, Point radius)
    {
        double radians = Math.PI * angle / 180.0;

        if(Math.Abs(Math.Cos(radians)) < 0.00001 || Math.Abs(Math.Sin(radians)) < 0.00001)
            return radians;

        double stretchedAngle = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(radians) / Math.Abs(radius.Y), Math.Cos(radians) / Math.Abs(radius.X));
        int rotationOffset = (int)Math.Round(radians / (2.0 * Math.PI), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) -
                             (int)Math.Round(stretchedAngle / (2.0 * Math.PI), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        return stretchedAngle + rotationOffset * Math.PI * 2.0;
    }
}
```

Here are some examples.  Note that the first example you gave is incorrect - for those initial values, `DrawArc()` will have an endpoint of (0.58, 0.97), **not** (0.92, 0.33).

```
Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
double width = 100;
double height = 200;
double startAngle = 180;
double sweepAngle = 135;
DrawArcEndPointCalculator _endPointCalculator = new DrawArcEndPointCalculator();
Point lastPoint = _endPointCalculator.GetFinalPoint(startPoint, width, height, startAngle, sweepAngle);
Console.WriteLine("X = {0}, Y = {1}", lastPoint.X, lastPoint.Y);
//Output: X = 94.7213595499958, Y = 55.2786404500042

startPoint = new Point(0.251, 0.928);
width = 0.436;
height = 0.593;
startAngle = 169.51;
sweepAngle = 123.78;
_endPointCalculator.GetFinalPoint(startPoint, width, height, startAngle, sweepAngle);
//Returns X = 0.579143189905416, Y = 0.968627455618129

Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
double width = 20;
double height = 30;
double startAngle = 90;
double sweepAngle = 90;
_endPointCalculator.GetFinalPoint(startPoint, width, height, startAngle, sweepAngle);
//Returns X = 0, Y = 15
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this should do the job, really appreciate the help! Opened a new question also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515791/how-to-scrunchify-angles

Answer (score 2):

```
1) Given this:
xStart = .25
yStart = .92
startAngle = 169.51
sweepAngle = 123.78
Rx = .436  // this is radius width
Ry = .593  // this is radius height

2) Calculations:
centerX = xStart - Rx * cos(startAngle)
centerY = yStart - Ry * sin(startAngle)
endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle
xEnd = centerX + Rx * cos(endAngle)
yEnd = centerY + Ry * sin(endAngle)
```

So, your coordinate is (xEnd, yEnd).

Comment: Thanks for trying Loki, unfortunately, that is the calculation for a circular arc, not an elliptical one. The results are `xEnd=0.851` and `yEnd=0.267`, which is not the correct coordinates (if Rx and Ry were the same, it would be this calculation).

Comment: That is calculation for elliptical arc. You can examine that by runnig this simple program that generates a bitmap with an ellipse which is calculated based on above formulas: http://pastebin.com/kV0vWB5q . What program did you use to calculate expected position? I think that it may be wrong.

Comment: It certainly returns an arc on an ellipse path, but unfortunately it is not for an elliptical arc. See further edit above.

Answer (score 2):

the answer of "BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft" is correct but ... it rounds the radius point, a **PointF** has to be used instead a **Point**:

```
PointF radius = new PointF((float)width / 2, (float)height / 2);
```

I've extended a bit the class in order to have starting points as well, and another signature per method:

```
  public static class ChartHelper
{
    public static PointF GetStartingPoint(float x, float y, double width, double height, double startAngle, double sweepAngle)
    {
        return GetStartingPoint(new PointF(x, y), width, height, startAngle, sweepAngle);
    }

    public static PointF GetStartingPoint(PointF startPoint, double width, double height, double startAngle, double sweepAngle)
    {
        PointF radius = new PointF((float)width / 2, (float)height / 2);

        //Adjust the angles for the radius width/height
        startAngle = UnstretchAngle(startAngle, radius);

        //Calculate the starting point
        return new PointF
        {
            X = (float)(Math.Cos(startAngle) + 1) * radius.X + startPoint.X,
            Y = (float)(Math.Sin(startAngle) + 1) * radius.Y + startPoint.Y,
        };
    }

    public static PointF GetFinalPoint(float x, float y, double width, double height, double startAngle, double sweepAngle)
    {
        return GetFinalPoint(new PointF(x, y), width, height, startAngle, sweepAngle);
    }

    public static PointF GetFinalPoint(PointF startPoint, double width, double height, double startAngle, double sweepAngle)
    {
        PointF radius = new PointF((float)width / 2, (float)height / 2);
        double endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle;
        double sweepDirection = (sweepAngle < 0 ? -1 : 1);

        //Adjust the angles for the radius width/height
        startAngle = UnstretchAngle(startAngle, radius);
        endAngle = UnstretchAngle(endAngle, radius);

        //Determine how many times to add the sweep-angle to the start-angle
        double angleMultiplier = (double)Math.Floor(2 * sweepDirection * (endAngle - startAngle) / Math.PI) + 1;
        angleMultiplier = Math.Min(angleMultiplier, 4);

        //Calculate the final resulting angle after sweeping
        double calculatedEndAngle = startAngle + angleMultiplier * Math.PI / 2 * sweepDirection;
        calculatedEndAngle = sweepDirection * Math.Min(sweepDirection * calculatedEndAngle, sweepDirection * endAngle);

        //Calculate the final point
        return new PointF
        {
            X = (float)(Math.Cos(calculatedEndAngle) + 1) * radius.X + startPoint.X,
            Y = (float)(Math.Sin(calculatedEndAngle) + 1) * radius.Y + startPoint.Y,
        };
    }

    private static double UnstretchAngle(double angle, PointF radius)
    {
        double radians = Math.PI * angle / 180.0;

        if (Math.Abs(Math.Cos(radians)) < 0.00001 || Math.Abs(Math.Sin(radians)) < 0.00001)
            return radians;

        double stretchedAngle = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(radians) / Math.Abs(radius.Y), Math.Cos(radians) / Math.Abs(radius.X));
        double rotationOffset = (double)Math.Round(radians / (2.0 * Math.PI), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) -
                             (double)Math.Round(stretchedAngle / (2.0 * Math.PI), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        return stretchedAngle + rotationOffset * Math.PI * 2.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this of help:

[The Mathematics of ArcSegment](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/01/Mathematics-of-ArcSegment.html)