# Given bounding rectangle, starting angle, and sweep angle, how to determine points of the arc endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, trigonometry

Given a bounding rectangle, starting angle and the sweep angle, how do I determine the points of each end of the arc?

```
private void myPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)   
{   
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;   

   Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(242, 299, 200, 300);   
   Pen penRed = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);   

   g.DrawArc(penRed, rc, 18, -108);   

   // TODO - Determine Point of each end of arc   
   // Point pt1 = ???
   // Point pt2 = ???
}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like less of a programming question, and more of a math question. You would probably be best to find out the formula for calculating what you are looking for, then apply that formula to your code. If you are stuck on that, you could post what you have tried, along with the formula you are attempting to implement. Then we could help with that.

Comment: You need to be able to evaluate that curve -> draw it by yourself -> there are plenty of algorithms out there, do a web search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the equation of an ellipse from this excellent [Mathematics answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/687384/283855) We can calculate the start and end points of your ellipse, given the start angle and sweep.

First, we need the center of the bounding box, so we know how to shift the coordinates. That's simply

```
Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(242, 299, 200, 300);

int cX = (rc.Left + rc.Right) / 2;
int cY = (rc.Bottom + rc.Top) / 2;

// For debugging purposes, let's mark that point.
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, Rectangle.FromLTRB(cX - 3, cY - 3, cX + 3, cY + 3));
```

We then need to convert the angles from degrees into radians, and change the clockwise angle to a counter-clockwise angle like so:

```
double minTheta = (Math.PI / 180) * (360 - start);
double maxTheta = (Math.PI / 180) * (360 - (start + sweep));
```

We'll also define 2 helper functions, the first to normalize an angle (map arbitrary angles into the range 0-360) and the second to adjust the calculated (x, y) coordinates into the correct quadrant. (Given that positive y is actually down on the form)

```
public double NormalizeAngle(double angle)
{
    while (angle >= 360) angle -= 360;
    while (angle < 0) angle += 360;
    return angle;
}
public void AdjustCoordinatesForAngle(double angle, ref double x, ref double y)
{
    if (angle > 0 && angle <= 90)
    {
        x *= 1;
        y *= 1;
    }
    else if (angle >= 90 && angle < 180)
    {
        x *= -1;
        y *= 1;
    }
    else if (angle >= 180 && angle < 270)
    {
        x *= -1;
        y *= -1;
    }
    else if (angle >= 270 && angle < 360)
    {
        x *= 1;
        y *= -1;
    }
}
```

We now have enough information to calculate the start and end points.

```
double minTheta = (Math.PI / 180) * (360 - start);
double maxTheta = (Math.PI / 180) * (360 - (start + sweep));

double a = width / 2.0;
double b = height / 2.0;

double denom = Math.Pow(a, 2) * Math.Pow(Math.Tan(minTheta), 2);
denom = denom / Math.Pow(b, 2);
denom = Math.Sqrt(denom + 1);

double x = Math.Abs(a / denom);
double y = Math.Abs((a * Math.Tan(minTheta)) / denom);

start = NormalizeAngle(start);
this.AdjustCoordinatesForAngle(start, ref x, ref y);
```

Those coordinates are relative to the bounding box's center, so we offset it using the center point we calculated above:

```
x += cX;
y += cY;
```

We can now draw the point:

```
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Purple, new Rectangle((int)x - 3, (int)y - 3, 6, 6));
```

All together the paint function looks like this:

```
private void myPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    double start = 18;
    double sweep = -108;

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    g.Clear(Color.Black);

    Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(200, 10, 200, 300);

    int cX = (rc.Left + rc.Right) / 2;
    int cY = (rc.Bottom + rc.Top) / 2;

    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, Rectangle.FromLTRB(cX - 3, cY - 3, cX + 3, cY + 3));

    int width = rc.Width;
    int height = rc.Height;

    if (start >= 360) start -= 360;

    double minTheta = (Math.PI / 180) * (360 - start);
    double maxTheta = (Math.PI / 180) * (360 - (start + sweep));

    double a = width / 2.0;
    double b = height / 2.0;

    double denom = Math.Pow(a, 2) * Math.Pow(Math.Tan(minTheta), 2);
    denom = denom / Math.Pow(b, 2);
    denom = Math.Sqrt(denom + 1);

    double x = Math.Abs(a / denom);
    double y = Math.Abs((a * Math.Tan(minTheta)) / denom);

    start = NormalizeAngle(start);
    this.AdjustCoordinatesForAngle(start, ref x, ref y);

    x += cX;
    y += cY;

    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Purple, new Rectangle((int)x - 3, (int)y - 3, 6, 6));

    denom = Math.Pow(a, 2) * Math.Pow(Math.Tan(maxTheta), 2);
    denom = denom / Math.Pow(b, 2);
    denom = Math.Sqrt(denom + 1);

    x = Math.Abs(a / denom);
    y = Math.Abs((a * Math.Tan(maxTheta)) / denom);

    double endAngle = (start + sweep);
    endAngle = NormalizeAngle(endAngle);
    this.AdjustCoordinatesForAngle(endAngle, ref x, ref y);

    x += cX;
    y += cY;

    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, new Rectangle((int)x - 3, (int)y - 3, 6, 6));


    Pen penRed = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, rc);
    g.DrawArc(penRed, rc, (float)start, (float)sweep);
}
```

I painted the window background black to make the boxes and lines stand out better, and I left in some additional drawing elements, so it is easier to see what's happening in the calculations above.

Placing the code into a form, and associating with the form's paint event produces this result:

[image: Final Result]

One final note, due to rounding, the start and end points may be off by a pixel or two. If you want more accuracy, you'd have to draw the arc yourself.

Comment: This was absolutely perfect!  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: After further testing, this solution works for the start and sweep angle of 18,-108.  But if I use 18,-188, one of the end points is in the wrong position.  I'd add another image if I could.  I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Imagine a vertical line through the center point.  The current implementation always puts the first point where it should be.  But the second point is correct only if the arc doesn't cross the imaginary vertical line. It always puts both points on either the left half, or the right half.

Comment: After further testing, it appears the calculated x value is always greater than the x value of the center point.

Comment: Update coming. I flipped both the coordinate system (-y is up) and the angle (+theta is clockwise). Plus the Tan() in the formula is only defined in a certain range.

Comment: @KellyJohnson Fixed the bugs.

Comment: You're solution works perfectly.  I added a timer to increase the sweep angle.  When it reached 360 (caught up to the starting point) I reset the sweep angle back to 0, then increased the start angle.  I also tested for both positive and negative sweep angles.  Everything worked perfectly.  Thank you for your help!!